# Check radiobutton on tabbing

Tags: jquery, forms, radio-button, jquery-events

If I tab through form elements that include radiobuttons, is there a way to select (check) radiobutton when I tab into it?  When I tab into text field it gets a focus, which is visually clear, but not the radio button. I think it should be possible with jQuery.

This will select it but not on focus, a click later

```
$(':input:visible').keypress(function(event) {
       if(event.keyCode == '9' && $(this).is(':radio')) { // Tab
            $(this).attr('checked', true);
       }
});
```

Comment: What have you tried? Being a >2000 user you could already know how to ask a question here. Do you have a problem with handling the `focus` event, or making a radio button checked? Btw, the radio button also gets focus when you tab on it (should be also indicated by your browser, if you have not overridden the default style), and pressing Space for example makes it checked (at least in my browser).

Comment: I can check the button with a mouse click. My question is -- can it be checked on tabbing? It is possible I am dealing with some CSS conflicts but I am in no position to change that due to other dependencies that may not be obvious. I am trying to solve a local case. Do you have other suggestions?

Comment: When you tab or click on it, an `onfocus` event will fire on the radio button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try handling the `focus` event:

```
$(':radio').focus(function () {
    this.checked = true;
});
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/q9Hq9/)

Comment: I like this it takes two tabs in IE... why?

Comment: @santa I have left a `tabindex=1` on the `input`, and in IE, a different element comes next (I am not sure what). It has nothing to do with the "solution" itself, the `focus` event always fires when the radiobutton gets focus.